# Why does the 'int' object is not callable error occur when using the sum() function?

Tags: python, sum, python-2.7, callable

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an error when using the sum function on a range.

Here is the code:

```
data1 = range(0, 1000, 3)
data2 = range(0, 1000, 5)
data3 = list(set(data1 + data2)) # makes new list without duplicates
total = sum(data3) # calculate sum of data3 list's elements
print total
```

And here is the error:

```
line 8, in <module> total2 = sum(data3)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I found this explanation for the error:

> In Python a "callable" is usually a function. The message means you are treating a number (an >"int") as if it were a function (a "callable"), so Python doesn't know what to do, so it >stops.

I've also read that sum() is capable of being used on lists, so I'm wondering what is going wrong here?

I just tried it in an IDLE module and it worked fine.  However, it doesn't work in the python interpreter. Any ideas on how that can be?

Comment: This works perfectly for me... did you name a variable `sum` before calling the function?

Comment: Just edited original. I'm using IDE. Works in IDLE, as you mentioned. IDE is running Python 2.7. This is weird.

Comment: You said "it doesn't work in IEP". What's IEP?

Comment: An interactive editor for Python. http://code.google.com/p/iep/

Comment: @jamylak 's answer fixed it. I had to restart the terminal.

Comment: You don't really need to convert your set back to a list... `sum()` will handle any sequence of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Implemented.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably redefined your "sum" function to be an integer data type.  So it is rightly telling you that an integer is not something you can pass a range.

To fix this, restart your interpreter.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data1 = range(0, 1000, 3)
>>> data2 = range(0, 1000, 5)
>>> data3 = list(set(data1 + data2)) # makes new list without duplicates
>>> total = sum(data3) # calculate sum of data3 list's elements
>>> print total
233168
```

If you shadow the `sum` builtin, you can get the error you are seeing

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> total = sum(data3) # calculate sum of data3 list's elements
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Also, note that `sum` will work fine on the `set` there is no need to convert it to a `list`

Answer (score 21):

This means that somewhere else in your code, you have something like:

```
sum = 0
```

Which shadows the builtin sum (which *is* callable) with an int (which isn't).

Comment: The code shown is the whole program. I wish it was that simple. Any other ideas?

Comment: @mattste restart your python interpreter and try it.

Answer (score 3):

In the interpreter its easy to restart it and fix such problems. If you don't want to restart the interpreter, there is another way to fix it:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> sum(l)
6
>>> sum = 0 # oops! shadowed a builtin!
>>> sum(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> import sys
>>> sum = sys.modules['__builtin__'].sum # -- fixing sum
>>> sum(l)
6
```

This also comes in handy if you happened to assign a value to any other builtin, like `dict` or `list`